# Getting unique values from nested Array using jq

Tags: json, command-line, terminal, jq

Trying to get unique values stored in items array for each group. somehow it's always mixed...

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "start": 1534425916,
  "stop": 1535030716,
  "groups": [
    {
      "group": "transmission",
      "data": {
        "events": 665762,
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "item": "manualni",
          "data": {
            "events": 389158,
          }
        },
        {
          "item": "automaticka",
          "data": {
            "events": 276604,
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": "vat",
      "data": {
        "events": 671924,
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "item": "ne",
          "data": {
            "events": 346221,
          }
        },
        {
          "item": "ano",
          "data": {
            "events": 325703,
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired result is the following:

```
{
  "id": "transmission",
  "value": [
    "manualni",
    "automaticka",
  ]
}
{
  "id": "vat",
  "value": [
    "ne",
    "ano"
  ]
}
```

Tried with this filter on command line:

```
| jq '{id: .groups[].group, value: [.groups[].items[].item]}'
```

Which results in the above mentioned mixed up result:

```
{
  "id": "transmission",
  "value": [
    "manualni",
    "automaticka",
    "ne",
    "ano"
  ]
}
{
  "id": "vat",
  "value": [
    "manualni",
    "automaticka",
    "ne",
    "ano"
  ]
}
```

Any idea how to receive the uniquified values here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the desired result. I think the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/) entry under .[] explains why it works.

```
jq '.groups[] | {"id": .group, "value": [.items[].item]}'
```